# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key <key> where <key> is not in the code (swift, Xcode 6)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, runtime-error

I have typed in a program, the code of which follows below, from a tutorial, trying to get back into coding after a number of years.

When I run the code, everything builds, but then it crashes with subject-line error above, naming a key which does not appear anywhere in my code ("helloText"). Full error output below.

The twist: at one point I had named one of the outlets "helloText" (now named "nameTextField").

I have looked in every file associated with the project I could find, and could not find "helloText". I also tried the menu item "clean."

Thanks for any guidance.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ConstructOStraws
//
//  Created by Eric on 11/12/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Eric. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        setupUI()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var helloButton: UIButton!

    func setupUI(){

        helloLabel.text = "Hello Swift!"
        helloLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        helloLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        nameTextField.placeholder = "Enter your name"

    helloButton.setTitle("Say Hell", forState: .Normal)

    }


    @IBAction func sayHelloAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        let name = nameTextField.text

        if name.isEmpty {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please Enter a Name.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {

            helloLabel.text = "Hello \(name)"
        }
    }

}
```

The Errors:

```
2014-11-12 15:23:10.521 ConstructOStraws[2048:67817] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ConstructOStraws.ViewController 0x7f82e866b420> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key helloText.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001043b7f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105efbbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001043b7b79 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001047cf7b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104301e80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000104f08c7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000104d67f98 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104d68588 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000104d687f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104d68c8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000104c87ca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104c88041 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104c9472c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104c3f061 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000104c41d2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000104c40bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    16  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000107a9b2a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042ed53c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042e3285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042e3045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042e2486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000104c40669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000104c43420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  ConstructOStraws                    0x00000001041d661e top_level_code + 78
    24  ConstructOStraws                    0x00000001041d665a main + 42
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001066d5145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key)

Comment: Please use the search.  There are many, many duplicates of this question.

Comment: There are a few cases that can cause this - perhaps you tied a `UITextField` to `helloText` before you renamed it, and the connection still exists to the old name. In your storyboard, click on the text field you connected and look at the Connections Inspector (Command-Option-5).

Comment: @NobodyNada: I thank you for your input. Please know that I did search, and while there are repeated references to similar errors, of the dozen I viewed, none addressed my particular issue. The example you cite presents a different solution to a different problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have renamed your IBOutlets then chances are you might not deleted the references of old references in your storyboard which might look as follows

[image: Attached Screenshot]

Delete the outlet reference with **yellow exclamation triangles** as shown in the screen. You can get to this screen by right clicking on your **view controller** object, next to **First Responder**, in your view controller's storyboard.

Comment: Is the proper methodology for renaming to use the inspector instead of directly in the code, to prevent this sort of thing?

Comment: There is one, if you select the outlet variable and right click on it, a pop menu will be shown with some options, choose Refactor followed by Rename and the updated name will be reflected in storyboard.